# WPF: Make a UserControl with a Treeview behave like a vanilla Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, treeview

I'm learning WPF, and I think I'm missing something with user controls. I'll try and demonstrate by example. Basically, suppose I have a treeview, and I want to bind a labels text to the treeviews selectedItem. This seems simple :

```
<!-- Window.xaml -->
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TreeView Name="MyTreeView">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item2"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>

    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Header}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Now, to complicate things I'll add a user control into the mix. The user control is basically a TreeView in a grid :

```
<!-- ExampleUserControl.xaml -->
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="UserControlTreeView">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item2"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The intent is to replace the vanilla treeview used above with the usercontrol, and have the labels content changed based on what is selected. So, I try something like this :

```
<Window>    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:ExampleUserControl1 x:Name="MyUserControl">            
        </local:ExampleUserControl1>

        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=SelectedItem.Header}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This compiles and runs, but when I select items in the treeview, the label doesn't change. I think I understand why : the user control contains a treeview, but is clearly not a treeview. I'm not sure on the best way to fix this. I can think of one way that seems problematic :

- Add a property 'SelectedItem' to the user control in code, that returns the treeviews selected item.

This would work for one property, or a few, but the thought of doing this for each property in treeview seems like a serious waste of code + time. Is there some way to still use the user control, but make it behave like a normal TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way.

Create a public property of type TreeView in your user control and return the treeview as shown below.

```
    //ExampleUserControl.xaml.cs
    public TreeView UTreeView
    {
        get
        {
            return UserControlTreeView;
        }
    }
```

Then use this property in Window.xaml as given below.

```
  <local:ExampleUserControl1 x:Name="MyUserControl">
    </local:ExampleUserControl1>

    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=UTreeView.SelectedItem.Header}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
```

Comment: Wow, that is remarkably simple. I feel I was over thinking this. Marking as answer, since it can easily be extended to other controls in the user control.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your reasoning about why it is not working. The SelectedItem property is not visible to the Label.

Instead of using a UserControl to simply host a TreeView, you can use a TreeView like you would normally, but bind to it's ItemsSource. For Example:

```
<!--MainWindow.xaml-->
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
        <coll:ArrayList x:Key="data">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </coll:ArrayList>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TreeView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}" x:Name="tv1"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=tv1, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For this example, I am using a StaticResource, which is not dynamic... **BUT**, all you have to do is bind to the itemsource. This is the best way IMHO to handle multiple TreeViews.

**EDIT:**

Looking again, I see that you were more so trying to get the usercontrol to behave like a treeview, not just get the results.

You can not do exactly what you're talking about with a UserControl.

What you would want to do is make a new class which extends treeview. It doesn't need to be a user control.

Answer (score 2):

Child controls are not accessible from outside like this. One way is to have wrapper property in code behind for `SelectedItem` and bind to that from outside which you already mentioned.

But i would suggest to use `Tag` property of UserControl to contain the reference of `TreeView` and bind to `Tag` property from outside. That way you don't have to create multiple properties in code behind.

Use [x:Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to bind to TreeView:

```
<UserControl Tag="{Binding Source={x:Reference UserControlTreeView}}">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="UserControlTreeView">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item2"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Bind label control now:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl,
                         Path=Tag.SelectedItem.Header}"/>
```

Comment: This is very cool. Did not realize you could use bind Tag in this way.

Comment: That's the beauty of XAML.